# Redis Lua that will create a default JSON on numincrby exception?

Tags: redis, lua, redisjson

I am trying to run numincrby on a nested JSON that might or might not exist via multiple threads. If the key does not exist, a default JSON structure has to be created with the value 0 and the value incremented.

e.g.
`JSON.NUMINCRBY "KEY" ".PATH1.COUNT" 5.0` on `{'KEY': {'PATH1': {...}}}` or `{'KEY': {...}}` should result in `{'KEY': {'PATH1': {'COUNT' : 5.0}}}`

Unfortunately the default behaviour of RedisJSON is throw an error.

How can I achieve this behaviour with a Lua?

Comment: If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

In Lua you can make decitions by condition at re/defining too, e.g.

```
function flipflop(b)
local b = b == false and true or false
return(b)
end
```

At work...

```
> chk = true
> chk
true
> chk = flipflop(chk)
> chk
false
> chk = flipflop(chk)
> chk
true
```

EDIT: Impression to my Comment
[image]

Comment: I'm trying to create an array that is compatible with regular RedisJSON commands after creation. I'm looking at this blob and getting very confused as I am not familiar with Lua at all: https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON/blob/master/benchmarks/lua/json-set-path.lua

Comment: You mean how to construct a JSON string from Lua side? - Than try this in redis-cli: ```eval 'return(cjson.encode({KEY = {PATH1 = {COUNT = 5.0}}}))' 0```
  Becomes: ```"{\"KEY\":{\"PATH1\":{\"COUNT\":5}}}"```